# How to compile multiple schemas but have JAXB combine them into the same object factory?

Tags: jaxb, factory

Due to size and complexity we have split some of our schemas into multiple files schemas.
Compiling each of these works fine, but the trouble is, that the ObjectFactory class that is created by the JAXB compiler then always contains only the definitions from the last schema compiled. Can one teach JAXB to combine those schemas such, that the ObjectFactory-class is able to handle the classes from multiple schema files? And if so: how can one specify this?

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectFactory file is created per java package. So if you compile all your schemas in one destination java package then the last generated `ObjectFactory.java` will replace the previous.
If you want to keep all of them you should separate java packages just like you separated xml schemas.